# C# PInvoking user32.dll on a 64 bit system

Tags: c#, 64-bit, pinvoke, 32-bit, user32

Is it wrong to pinvoke user32.dll on 64 bit Windows, from a 64 bit app?  I've done this successfully a number of times and never had an error, but it seems contradictory.  Should I look for user64.dll instead?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The name `user32.dll` is misleading. It's the 64 bit version of `user32.dll` you're calling. The 64 bit version is located at `%windir%\System32\user32.dll`.

A 32-bit version is included for compatibility with 32-bit applications. It's located at `%windir%\SysWOW64\user32.dll`. You can inspect them using the `dumpbin` utility:

System32\user32.dll:

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
        8664 machine (x64)
```

SysWOW64\user32.dll:

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
         14C machine (x86)
```

Comment: It is misleading now, but it was originally named such to differentiate between 16 and 32 bit wasn't it? But they can hardly change the name, that'd break too many things...

Comment: Yeah. I distinctly remember general protection faults caused by "USER.EXE" in Windows 3.1 in my childhood days.

Comment: Gotta love how the System32 directory is still called that in 64 bit windows :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no user64.dll for the exact same reason you just described, .NET program can be agnostic to CPU architecture so the same code needs to work on x86 and x64.
If you take your program to x86 platform, it will still run without any modifications.
I guess that when they named user32.dll, they didn't have those scenarios in mind.