# Why windows 64 still makes use of user32.dll etc?

Tags: winapi, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I think under windows x64, it still uses user32.dll and a bunch of other 32 bit libraries.  Why there is no user64.dll?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_api#Versions

Comment: How on Earth is this question off topic?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540741

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll` *is* a 64-bit library.
The 32-bit version is in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll`.

They can't change any names because that would break all sorts of programs with hard-coded paths.

Answer (score 2):

The names "user32" and "system32" and so on existed long before the modern 64-bit editions of Windows. The names were intended to distinguish them from the 16-bit versions, not from the 64-bit versions. On 64-bit Windows, it's still not 16-bit, so it's still "system32", "user32", and so on.

Nobody planned it that way, it just happened.

Comment: Change dll filename will create trouble linking / loading dlls have to handle 32/64 with different names every time. The OS simply redirects system folders when a program is running in 32-bit mode.