# SendKey Keyboard Mouse simulation with 64-bit system

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a set of send key functions that I wrote a while ago. It was working in 32 bit systems. Now I tested it again and realised it doesn't work in my new win7 64 bit system any more.
I found a few articles on the net, and followed [their way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596163/sendinput-keys-in-win32-win64-machines) to make the Input32/64 functions. However it doesn't seem to work.

`Dim result As Integer = SendInput(1, input, cbSize)`

always return 0 and no keystroke was simulated. Could you please take a look?

(Note: I only made the KEYBOARDINPUT64 structure, it didn't work, so I didn't make MOUSEINPUT64 or HARDWAREINPUT64 structures...)

```
''mouse functions

Private Shared Sub SendMouseInput(ByVal flags As MOUSEEVENTF, ByVal point As System.Drawing.Point)
    If Marshal.SizeOf(New IntPtr()) = 8 Then
        SendMouseInput64(flags, point)
    Else
        SendMouseInput32(flags, point)
    End If
End Sub
Private Shared Sub SendMouseInput64(ByVal flags As MOUSEEVENTF, ByVal point As System.Drawing.Point)
    Dim screen As Rectangle = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds
    Dim globalx As Integer = CInt((65535 * point.X) / screen.Width) ' x scale from 0 to 65535
    Dim globaly As Integer = CInt((65535 * point.Y) / screen.Height) ' y scale from 0 to 65535
    Dim input As New INPUT64
    input.dwType = InputType.Mouse
    input.mi.dx = globalx
    input.mi.dy = globaly
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF.ABSOLUTE Or flags
    input.mi.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
    input.mi.mouseData = 0
    input.mi.time = 0
    SendInput(1, input, Marshal.SizeOf(input))
End Sub
Private Shared Sub SendMouseInput32(ByVal flags As MOUSEEVENTF, ByVal point As System.Drawing.Point)
    Dim screen As Rectangle = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds
    Dim globalx As Integer = CInt((65535 * point.X) / screen.Width) ' x scale from 0 to 65535
    Dim globaly As Integer = CInt((65535 * point.Y) / screen.Height) ' y scale from 0 to 65535
    Dim input As New INPUT32
    input.dwType = InputType.Mouse
    input.mi.dx = globalx
    input.mi.dy = globaly
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF.ABSOLUTE Or flags
    input.mi.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
    input.mi.mouseData = 0
    input.mi.time = 0
    SendInput(1, input, Marshal.SizeOf(input))
End Sub

''keyboard functions
Private Shared Sub SendKeyInput(ByVal flags As KEYEVENTF, ByVal key As Int16)
    If Marshal.SizeOf(New IntPtr()) = 8 Then
        SendKeyInput64(flags, key)
    Else
        SendKeyInput32(flags, key)
    End If
End Sub
Private Shared Sub SendKeyInput64(ByVal flags As KEYEVENTF, ByVal key As Int16)
    Dim input As New INPUT64
    Dim ki As New KEYBDINPUT64
    input.dwType = InputType.Keyboard
    input.ki = ki
    input.ki.wVk = key
    input.ki.wScan = 0
    input.ki.time = 0
    input.ki.dwFlags = flags
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim cbSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(INPUT64))
    Dim result As Integer = SendInput(1, input, cbSize)
    If result = 0 Then Console.WriteLine("SendKeyInput:" & Marshal.GetLastWin32Error)
End Sub
Private Shared Sub SendKeyInput32(ByVal flags As KEYEVENTF, ByVal key As Int16)
    Dim input As New INPUT32
    Dim ki As New KEYBDINPUT32
    input.dwType = InputType.Keyboard
    input.ki = ki
    input.ki.wVk = key
    input.ki.wScan = 0
    input.ki.time = 0
    input.ki.dwFlags = flags
    input.ki.dwExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim cbSize As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(INPUT32))
    Dim result As Integer = SendInput(1, input, cbSize)
    If result = 0 Then Messaging.Instance.ReportError("MouseKeyboard::SendKeyInput:" & Marshal.GetLastWin32Error)
End Sub

''lower level input functions
<DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SendInput(ByVal nInputs As Integer, ByRef pInputs As INPUT64, ByVal cbSize As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function SendInput(ByVal nInputs As Integer, ByRef pInputs As INPUT32, ByVal cbSize As Integer) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function BlockInput(ByVal fBlockIt As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, pack:=1)> _
Private Structure INPUT64
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public dwType As InputType
    <FieldOffset(8)> Public mi As MOUSEINPUT
    <FieldOffset(8)> Public ki As KEYBDINPUT64
    <FieldOffset(8)> Public hi As HARDWAREINPUT
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, pack:=1)> _
Private Structure INPUT32
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public dwType As InputType
    <FieldOffset(4)> Public mi As MOUSEINPUT
    <FieldOffset(4)> Public ki As KEYBDINPUT32
    <FieldOffset(4)> Public hi As HARDWAREINPUT
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, pack:=1)> _
Private Structure MOUSEINPUT
    Public dx As Int32
    Public dy As Int32
    Public mouseData As Int32
    Public dwFlags As MOUSEEVENTF
    Public time As Int32
    Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, pack:=1)> _
Private Structure KEYBDINPUT64
    <FieldOffset(0)> Public wVk As Int16
    <FieldOffset(2)> Public wScan As Int16
    <FieldOffset(4)> Public dwFlags As KEYEVENTF
    <FieldOffset(12)> Public time As Int32
    <FieldOffset(16)> Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, pack:=1)> _
Private Structure KEYBDINPUT32
    Public wVk As Int16
    Public wScan As Int16
    Public dwFlags As KEYEVENTF
    Public time As Int32
    Public dwExtraInfo As IntPtr
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, pack:=1)> _
Private Structure HARDWAREINPUT
    Public uMsg As Int32
    Public wParamL As Int16
    Public wParamH As Int16
End Structure
Private Enum InputType As Integer
    Mouse = 0
    Keyboard = 1
    Hardware = 2
End Enum
<Flags()> _
Private Enum MOUSEEVENTF As Integer
    MOVE = &H1
    LEFTDOWN = &H2
    LEFTUP = &H4
    RIGHTDOWN = &H8
    RIGHTUP = &H10
    MIDDLEDOWN = &H20
    MIDDLEUP = &H40
    XDOWN = &H80
    XUP = &H100
    VIRTUALDESK = &H400
    WHEEL = &H800
    ABSOLUTE = &H8000
End Enum
<Flags()> _
Private Enum KEYEVENTF As Integer
    KEYDOWN = 0
    EXTENDEDKEY = 1
    KEYUP = 2
    [UNICODE] = 4
    SCANCODE = 8
End Enum
```

Comment: Are you sure you've got the struct layout right? Check with `FIELD_OFFSET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so much a solution to the problem, but have you tried the InputSimulator library: https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

I've used it on both 32/64-bit versions of Windows without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

Please check  out this.
[C# PInvoking user32.dll on a 64 bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540741/c-sharp-pinvoking-user32-dll-on-a-64-bit-system)

I imagine this also applies to the other user32.dll calls...

1. Use IntPtr instead of UIntrPtr: The UIntPtr type is not CLS-compliant
2. NEVER use "int" or "integer" as lParam. Your code WILL crash on 64-bit windows. ONLY use IntPtr, a "ref" structure, or an "out" structure.
3. NEVER use "bool", "int", or "integer" as the return value. Your core WILL crash on 64-bit windows. ONLY use IntPtr. It's not safe to use bool - pInvoke cannot marshal an IntPtr to a boolean.
4. Use "IntPtr" as the return value, EVEN if the message says it doesn't return any useful information.
5. Microsoft defines the Msg member of the System.Windows.Forms.Message structure to be System.Int32[1]. At the same time the SendMessage native API defines message as type UINT[2], which is a 32-bit unsigned value.[3]
   A listing of common Msg codes can be found here: http://www.vbcode.com/Asp/showsn.asp?theID=11797
6. You can safely type "hWnd" as an "IntPtr" instead of a "HandleRef", but make sure you understand what you are doing. If you are operating on a window handle provided by an unmanaged component or external application, things will just work (as well as can ever be guaranteed when other apps are free to manipulate the window themselves). However, using IntPtr with managed forms and controls may cause your code to crash under race conditions, because .NET can and will dispose of your window handle during the call. Used properly, GC.KeepAlive() can help with this. None of this has anything to do with pinning, which would NOT help here. Pinning is about keeping data from moving around; using a HandleRef or GC.KeepAlive is about preventing the runtime from destroying your handle.
7. When passing integer values to lParam and wParam, use IntPtr as they get  attributes by default. You should avoid mixing IntPtr and Integer as parameter types. Use IntPtr.
8. The wParam and lParam paramters are defined as type WPARAM and LPARAM respectivly
   WPARAM is defined as UINT_PTR
   LPARAM is defined as LONG_PTR 
   LONG_PTR is "Signed long type for pointer precision." and is a signed 32-bit or signed 64-bit depending on the platform.
   UINT_PTR is "Unsigned INT_PTR", and is unsigned 32-bit or unsigned 64-bit depending on the platform.

Source http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SendMessage

Also if you are in a pinch...
[SendInput Keys in Win32 & Win64 machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596163/sendinput-keys-in-win32-win64-machines)